# image darken/opacity

Tags: javascript, image, opacity

A quickie, is it possible to have an image darkened using javascript or something?

I don't need it on mouseovers or anything, just for the image to appear disabled (could I change the opacity of it using a style tag even?).

How would I do?

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sctkz/)? (Note, that works in Firefox latest, opacity thought can be browser and version specific.) (With `dark` example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sctkz/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method is to use opacity on the `img` and, if necessary, a background element with the color you want to add (note that opacity is somewhat [browser and version dependent](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html), this example works in Firefox, Chrome and I assume other Webkit browsers):

```
img {
    float: left;
}
#light {
    opacity: .4;
    float: left;
}
#dark {
    background: black;
    float: left;
}
#dark img {
    opacity: .6;
    display: inline;
}

<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
<img id="light" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
<div id="dark">
 <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sctkz/1/

And as David Thomas points out, if you are working with an with an alpha-transparency, you can add the `background-color` to the `img` itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/GfkeF/

According to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html#link2), full IE support using compatibility views can be gained adding:

```
opacity: .5; /* Firefox, Chrome[, Webkit?] */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Otherwise, as Ktash and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity) note, you can use simply:

```
opacity: .5; /* Firefox, Chrome[, Webkit?] */
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* In general, probably ok for IE */
```

Comment: Probably want to add `filter: alpha(opacity=40);` and `60` so that it has IE support.

Comment: @Ktash - [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html#link2) says to use something a bit more verbose.

Comment: If an image was used that had alpha-transparency, then a `background-color` could be used directly on the image (albeit that would be similarly affected by the `opacity` of the element itself, which may or may not be a problem). [Rudimentary demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GfkeF/).

Comment: @DavidThomas - I actually had tried that, but it didn't seem to work. Do you have a fiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, there is the much more verbose version of it, but using just `filter: alpha(opacity=XX)` is enough to be compatible with IE8 and below. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Comment: @Ktash - I assume the caveat is *If you don’t use this order, IE8-as-IE7 doesn’t apply the opacity, although IE8 and a pure IE7 do*, which I assume Quirksmode refers to IE's version rendering. I haven't yet come across Quirksmode being wrong about compatibility, but I assume it's possible.

Comment: Sorry, @JaredFarrish, I was putting the demo together as you responded =) My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GfkeF/) works in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04, I'm unsure about other browsers and platforms though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish IE 8 adds support for using `-ms-filter` as opposed to just `filter`, properly adding in the prefix. However, IE 8 still does support the `filter` property in CSS, so it isn't needed. There may be a case, if the user switches their browser mode from 8 to 7, in which opacity is not displayed (of if you set it using a meta tag), but for the common user, the `filter` alone will be enough.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Ah, I see what you mean. You're talking about a PNG with an alpha-transparency layer (or some other image format that supports it). That makes sense.

Comment: @Ktash - There's more to it [than that](http://davidwalsh.name/ie8-emulate-ie7). I haven't tested one way or the other, and I'm not real clear on the compatibility modes system IE has in later versions, but one is more compatible that the other. I do see your point, though it just has to do with if you're using a compatibility mode or not. I edited that into the answer.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, sorry; yeah. I should've explained myself better, really. My bad! =)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeah, that's what I was talking about when I said setting it via the `<meta>`. You can manually set which engine you want to render it in if you want, but by default it uses the most recent it can (or QuirksMode). Most people don't set that unless they have a very specific reason. But if he sets that, than he should probably be aware of all the changes (as IE7 in IE8/9 is not really IE7 and has many differences). And users switching it manually isn't really something I think you should have to worry about coding for.

Answer (score 3):

### Quick Solution

Use CSS to set the opacity. With jQuery, it's as simple as:

```
$('img').css('opacity',0.5);
```

Or without it would be easiest using straight CSS:

```
img.disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE support */
}
```

And add/remove that class.

### Other Solution

The other solution is to write the image to canvas, and literally go through pixel by pixel and make it darker. This is slower, and not well supported in older browsers, so I wouldn't recommend this. But it is possible to do. I would look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas) if you are interested in learning more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use opacity as a property for W3C compatible browsers (i.e. anything bot Internet Explorer) and as a filter for the rest.

```
opacity: 0.4; /* For non-IE browsers */
filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE */
```

You can also add a container element, say, a DIV, with an opaque background color:

```
<div class='image disabled'><img ... /></div>
```

And then have this CSS:

```
div.image {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.image.disabled {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

div.image.disabled img {        
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set Opacity through CSS, e.g.:

```
img {
    opacity : 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use jquery for browser compatible opacity :

**Step1 :** Include jquery in the head of the page.

**Step2 :** Add class="disabled" to the disabled images.

**Step3 :** Then write below lines in a script tag in the head of the page

$(function(){

$('.disabled').fadeTo(0.5);

})